# What is the command line shortcut to uncomment a previously commented line?

Tags: command-line, bash, keyboard-shortcuts, terminal

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> can only comment out, on subsequent invocations simply adding multiple comment characters (hashes) instead of toggling on / off the comment. How to uncomment a previously commented line or toggle the comments?

Comment: `bind -l | grep comment` doesn't show anything but `insert-comment`.

Comment: It's alt + #, not alt + shift + 3. You only think that because on your keyboard, # is shift + 3 but this isn't true for other keyboard layouts.

Comment: `Alt`+`a` and then `Del`?

Comment: @Cyrus You mean `Ctrl`+`a` (and then `Ctrl`+`d`).

Comment: @JoL: Almost. I meant `Ctrl`+`a` and then `Del`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question is tagged [bash](/questions/tagged/bash). This answer is specifically for Bash. Tested in GNU Bash 5.2.15.

Define the following shell function:

```bash
function _toggle_comment {
case "$READLINE_LINE" in
   \#* )
        ((READLINE_POINT--))
        READLINE_LINE="${READLINE_LINE###}"
        ;;
   *   )
        READLINE_LINE="#$READLINE_LINE"
        ((READLINE_POINT++))
        ;;
esac
}
```

and bind it to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>#</kbd>:

```
bind -x '"\e#":_toggle_comment'
```

(If in your keyboard layout <kbd>#</kbd> is in fact <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> then the binding will re-define <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> you mentioned.)

[`READLINE_LINE`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html#index-READLINE_005fLINE) and [`READLINE_POINT`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html#index-READLINE_005fPOINT) are exactly for this kind of tricks. Upon <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>#</kbd>, depending on whether a leading `#` is there or not in the command line, the function removes it or adds it, and moves the insertion point accordingly.

Comment: Excellent. Note that if you put the `bind` command in a `.sh` file (e.g. together with the toggle function to make the key binding persist e.g. from `~/.bashrc`), you need to `source` the shell script (to avoid `bind: warning: line editing not enabled`).

Answer (score 3):

Use a more powerful code editor than that built into Terminal, such as [Kate](https://kate-editor.org/about-kate/). <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> removes comment (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> comments the line). See [ShortcutsWorld](https://shortcutworld.com/Kate/win/Kate_Shortcuts) for more.

There are [numerous code editors](https://www.tecmint.com/best-open-source-linux-text-editors/) with features far beyond those of Terminal itself; some can be installed as the Terminal editor.